# www a-record vs cname-record

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, a-record

I have set up DNS for my website so that `example.com` is an `A` record (pointing to the IP), but I don't know what to do about `www.example.com`.

I intend to add a `CNAME` record `www.example.com` so it would become an alias of `example.com`.

BUT, I've been checking my settings with https://intodns.com and it shows:

> ERROR: I could not get any A records
>   for www.example.com!

The error clears if I change `www` to `A` record. Is there a "rule" requiring that?

Comment: Did you remember to add an extra dot "." to the end of the domain in the CNAME record?  It should be "www.example.com.", not "www.example.com"

Comment: Can you share your cname entry?

Comment: Yes, they are FQDNs :). The domain name is cexa.ro

Answer (score 20):

The difference between having an A record vs CNAME for www would be an extra look up. In case of the CNAME the after figuring out that www is a CNAME to example.com, another look will be done for example.com.

Other than that if you are planning to use a CDN or a 3 party acceleration service then a CNAME would come into play. Example a lookup of www.google.com results in the following. Notice the difference in TTL of www.l.google.com and www.google.com

```
www.google.com.     36545   IN  CNAME   www.l.google.com.
www.l.google.com.   294     IN  A       209.85.153.104
```

This gives the flexibility of changing the record, keeping a lower TTL, doing fancy stuff like geo redirection, if employing third party services.

In your case it doesn't matter since you are pointing both to the same IP.

Answer (score 4):

There is no rule that the `www.` address needs to be an A record.  It is very common for a web site to be a `CNAME` to something else.  For example:

```
$ host www.google.com
www.google.com is an alias for www.l.google.com.
```

Or:

```
$ host www.kodak.com
www.kodak.com is an alias for www.Kodak.com.edgekey.net.
```

If things aren't working for you, it suggests a configuration error.  Without seeing your actual DNS records it's hard to help out, but using command line tools like `dig` can help you debug the problem by showing you exactly what DNS records are being exposed by your name servers.

Comment: The actual domain is cexa.ro. I've had the CNAME deleted for the nigh and I've just re-added it. CNAME www.cexa.ro. alias for cexa.ro. From your answer and from Sameer's I understand that if the resulting IP is the same it makes no difference (I'm not concerned by the extra lookup). Thanks!